# TabHost empty on rotation Android by using onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, rotation, android-tabhost, onconfigurationchanged

I have a problem with onConfigurationChanged and TabHost.
Because my Activity restart on rotation, I found this very helpful post:
[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

I sort gui elements out to the function InitialGui()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    InitialGui();
}
```

Override onConfigurationChanged and call InitialGui()

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    InitialGui();
}
```

Inside AndroidManifest

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyAndroidAppActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
```

For simplicity I create a new project based on
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/
with only mentioned changes.
This is btw the InitialGui function

```
public void InitialGui()
{
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    // Android tab
    Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Android")
      .setIndicator("Android")
      .setContent(intentAndroid);

    // Apple tab
    Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Apple")
      .setIndicator("Apple")
      .setContent(intentApple);

    // Windows tab
    Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, WindowsActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Windows")
      .setIndicator("Windows")
      .setContent(intentWindows);

    // Blackberry tab
    Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, BlackBerryActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Berry")
      .setIndicator("Berry")
      .setContent(intentBerry);

    // add all tabs 
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBerry);

    //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
```

My Problem are the empty TabHosts after rotation, doesnt matter witch Tab is clicked nothing is displayed. Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: because you are using intent in tab and that activities-(started by using intent which is not present in current activity) data is not stored in your object that is returned (only the tab host activities data is contained)

Comment: but why start these intents on the first time? there isn't more code.
something like

     Intent i = new Intent(this, cls);
     startActivity(i);

start all threads again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to complex, there is no need to setContentView(R.layout.myLayout); or something else. Simply prevent a call of onCreate method by override onConfigurationChanged.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

this works for me.